# Fixing hidden png images in IE6

Tags: html, internet-explorer, png

I am using [Drew Diller’s DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) solution to fix the common problem of showing png images in IE6 browser and it works fine for visible PNGs.

Currently i have a hidden JQuery Dialog that  has some PNGs inside it, when user clicks on a link the dialog appears, and the PNGs inside that dialog appear not fixed in IE6. **Is there a way to fix the hidden PNGs too in IE6 ?**

Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can call `DD_belatedPNG.fix()` again after you load the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not tied to DD_Belated png, you could try replacing it with http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/ (also jquery), which you can call on specific elements if required.

Comment: Emmm, Thanks a lot. I have tried this now, the png images that appear directly in the page look fine, but the pngs inside the opened dialog are not visible at all :). I have also tried to apply it on a specific element at the click event but still not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Are those images by change being left aligned with a float: left or an align="left"?

If so you may need to add position: relative to the css of the images. I had to do this recently to get images to show under IE6.

I found the info here: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml

Hopefully this helps and good luck!